# Why can't I escape the decimal in my variable?

Tags: jquery, escaping

I have the following code:

```
<script>
var Var1 = "";
$(document).ready(function() {
window.Var1  = "Easy";
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
if $("div."+window.Var1).length > 0){ 
alert("success"); //DOESN'T WORK
}
});
</script>
```

This does not alert "success"

If I replace `window.Var1` with the word `Easy` (as show below), the alert works; so, the condition is being met but **the code isn't interpreting `$("div."+window.Var1)` as `$("div.Easy")`**

```
<script>
var Var1 = "";
$(document).ready(function() {
window.Var1  = "Easy";
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
if $("div.Easy").length > 0){ 
alert("success"); // WORKS
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: What is `\\.Var1` here? You should be getting syntax errors here, and those show up in your JavaScript console.

Comment: It's `window.Var1` with my butchered attempt at escaping the decimal. I thought that the code might be reading this as two classes separated by a decimal. Even without the `\\`, however, the code doesn't run.

Comment: The `.` is not a decimal. it is used to access the elements of `window`. So with the "\\" your code is not even valid JS

Comment: It should be `window.Var1` or `window['Var1']`. I don't know what good those slashed would do. The dot here is is not a decimal point, and I suggest to name this operator `dot` or [`property accessor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

Comment: I tried it first without using any escaping because I thought that it was the wrong path and it still doesn't interpret the variable correctly. (I'll edit the OP so the `\\` doesnt' detract from the question.)

Comment: Have you tried writing `console.log("div."+window.Var1)` to see what you're getting there?

Comment: First thing to check is what `console.log("div."+window.Var1)` produces, as that must be correct before anything else is going to function.

Comment: Don't count on the order that your `ready` functions will be called.

Comment: change if $("div."+window.Var1).length > 0){  to if ($("div."+window.Var1).length > 0){. You missed (

Comment: Apparently using stackoverflow is easier than looking at the console.

Comment: @ivo There was no issue with the console log because the issue wasn't related to that; apparently being snarky is easier than actually trying to help someone...

Comment: @gaetanoM If you want to write up that answer, I'll gladly accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @Snoops Funny how I see this "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" in the console when I run your original code.

Comment: @ivo  I'm here to learn, not bicker, so please see the accepted answer. Maybe it can help you out.

Comment: I'm not bickering. Just suggesting you use all the available tools. It will make you a better programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is in this line:

```
if $("div."+window.Var1).length > 0){
```

Change it to:

```
if ($("div."+window.Var1).length > 0){ 
   ^
```

You forgot the open parenthesis:

```js
var Var1 = "";
$(document).ready(function() {
  window.Var1  = "Easy";
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($("div."+window.Var1).length > 0){ 
    console.log("success"); //DOESN'T WORK
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div class="Easy">.....</div>
```